# An extern C pointer puzzler

Tags: c, pointers, linker

You are given the following two C files:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern uint32_t *foo;

int main() {
    printf("%p\n", foo);
    printf("%x\n", *foo);
}
```

and

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint32_t foo[2] = {0xDEADBEEF, 0xCAFEFEED};
```

Assuming you're running on an x86_64 processor, what happens when you compile and link these two files together? More importantly, why?

Answer (score 3):

There is separate "stack" site for puzzlers: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

In your case you are lying to your compiler. You define 'foo' as name for an array in second file and as a pointer in you 'main' file. array and pointer are different concepts.

If you change extern declaraion in main to be the same as in second module you will be ok:
extern uint32_t foo[];

Added: If you "inline" foo and replace
    extern uint32_t *foo;
with
    uint32_t foo[2] = {0xDEADBEEF, 0xCAFEFEED};
Then compiler will see that your variable is not a pointer but rather a name for an array. Exactly like when you do extern unit32_t foo[]. Check, for example, here:  [Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c).

Comment: The follow up is: why does the program run fine if you inline the extern declaration?

Comment: The puzzle site is http://puzzling.stackexchange.com, but I agree that the question is off-topic because it doesn't clearly describe the expected behavior versus what actually happens.

Comment: What do you mean by "inline extern declaration"?

Comment: Replace extern uint32_t *foo; with uint32_t foo[2] = {0xDEADBEEF, 0xCAFEFEED};

Comment: Then compiler will see that your variable is not a pointer but rather a name for an array. Exactly like when you do extern unit32_t foo[]. Check, for example, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c

Comment: ring0: Oh, don't link in the auxiliary file.

Comment: fukanchik: You know what is going on! But can you see why this explanation does not seem very clear? (e.g. Why doesn't the compiler know to decay the pointer when linking the two files together? Why isn't decaying the pointer a no-op?)

Answer (score 2):

You will get

```
DEADBEEFCAFEFEED
Segmentation fault
```

?

Because C arrays are stored directly, there is no such thing as intermediate reference or pointer to them. I think you'd expect that to happen:

1. C compiler puts two DEAD numbers somethere (consumes 8 bytes).
2. C compiler creates a pointer to that memory area and calls it *foo* (consumes additional 8 bytes).
3. Linker uses that pointer *foo* later in main file

Step 2 is easy to expect because in many cases arrays act like they are pointers, i.e.:

```
int a[2] = {1, 3};
...
*a
```

But they are **not** pointers, its just C compiler knows what you mean by saying `*a`. You can check it by taking reference:

```
int a[2] = {1, 2};  
printf("%p %p\n", a, &a);  /* Prints same values */
```

So here are whats really happens:

1. C compiler puts two DEAD numbers somethere and calls them *foo*
2. Linker uses that pointer *foo* later in main file. But linker do not know if *foo* was an array, so it treats it like traditional 8 byte pointer.

Comment: This answer has got the right idea but it is not written very well.

Comment: Edward, what is the purpose of this exercise?

Comment: Well, originally, I just wanted to share a distillation of a problem that has given me problems in the past (and has confused multiple colleagues of mine who /really/ should know better)--as other answers have pointed out, you never really have this problem when just C is involved; in the real world this situation invariably involves assembly/linker scripts at one end or another. But what I realized reading these answers is that it's not obviously clear what the best way to explain the *underlying principle* of the problem is.

Comment: I think there was a whole section in K&R book devoted to interplay between pointers and arrays.

Comment: _Underlying principle_ is "int v=2; int *p=&v" is memory allocated for a pointer to integer(s). that memory has name 'p', but integers which it points to would have different name and stored independently. There are 4 distinct hings here: 1) integer (uses memory), 2) his name (no memory consumed, just for compilation and linking), 3) pointer (uses memory), 4) pointer name (no memory).

Comment: While "int arr[2]" is memory allocated for two integers and that memory has name arr. Two distinct things are involved in this case: 1) 2 integers (with memory allocated for them) 2) name (arr) (which does not consume memory). If add "static" before the name it won't be visible at all and won't waste space in your compiled binary file.

Comment: Note - in the first case integer had name - 'v', while in the second two integers are nameless, they can only be referenced via dereferencing the array: arr[1]

Answer (score 1):

As the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28160564/an-extern-c-pointer-puzzler/28160707#28160707) pointed out, you lied to the compiler about the type of `foo`. Hence your program has undefined behavior, which in this case results in a segmentation fault.

When declaring an variable as `extern`, you should **never** put the `extern` statement into the `.c` file directly. You should **always** put the `extern` statement into a header file and then `#include` that header in any `.c` file that needs it. But most importantly, you should **always** include that header in the `.c` file that defines the variable, so that the compiler can verify the `extern` declaration against the variable definition.

So the code should have consisted of the three files shown below

#### foo.h

```
#include <stdint.h>
extern uint32_t *foo;
```

#### foo.c

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "foo.h"
uint32_t foo[2] = {0xDEADBEEF, 0xCAFEFEED};
```

#### main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "foo.h"

int main( void )
{
    printf("%p\n", (void *)foo);
    printf("%x\n", *foo);
}
```

In that case, the error messages that you get from `gcc` are

> foo.c:3: error: conflicting types for ‘foo’
>
> foo.h:2: error: previous declaration of ‘foo’ was here

And, of course, you need to fix the error by fixing `foo.h`

#### foo.h

```
#include <stdint.h>
extern uint32_t foo[];
```

Comment: This strategy is great! But it works less well when a linker script / assembler is serving the purpose of foo.c.

Comment: Yes, but that fundamentally changes the nature of the question. In essence, what you're asking is, "What C type corresponds to a given assembly type?". The programmer that develops the assembly, and creates/maintains the header file needs to be able to answer that question correctly.